# how to set an onClick event in progressbar with ActionbarSherlock?

Tags: android, onclick, progress-bar, actionbarsherlock

Im using the `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true)` to show a progressbar in the ActionbarSherlock. How can I set an onclick event to the image?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to set the progress bar clickable ?